# Possible EGR problem on Fiat Idea Multijet 1.3 Diesel

Tags: diesel, diagnostics, fiat, egr

I've been having issues with my 56 plate Fiat Idea for a while now. It seems to drive normally up to about 2500-3000 rpm where the car lurches a little, as though i shifted down a gear, the MIL light comes on and the car becomes incredibly sluggish. Not quite limp mode but sluggish.

My basic knowledge is telling me it could be a blocked EGR valve, and my code reader is reading two error codes relating to turbo intake, which could be indicative of an EGR fault I suppose?

I have ordered some EGR cleaner that you spray into the intake as the valve is located next to the gearbox linkage so there's no way to easily access it without having 5ft long arms made of elastic; otherwise I would attempt to clean the valve properly.

What's weird is that after a few restarts, the MIL light goes off and the engine functions fine, until I hit around 2500rpm again, where it goes into this near limp mode. And you can push the revs to the limiter in neutral without a problem.

What are your diagnoses on this problem? Am I wasting my time with the EGR? Also, what is the likelihood of it passing it's MOT in a couple of weeks time? The light is not currently on and if I can avoid going above 60mph, I can make it stay off until the MOT. But will their tests cause it to come on? And does the EGR effect emissions enough to cause it to fail?

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Could you post the exact codes you're seeing?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1470/675). Thank for a great question.

Comment: @Zaid I'm sorry but i don't have the codes at hand. If the MIL light returns i'll check the codes again and edit them into my question.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that the turbo is sometimes over-boosting, which is being detected by the engine MAP sensor.  The way that the engine ECU can control this over-boost to avoid engine damage is by limiting the amount of fuel injected into the engine, which would of course cause a sudden drop in power.  The over-boost could be being caused by a seized turbo waste gate.  If you are able to, check that the waste gate mechanism on the turbo is not seized.

Answer (score 0):

The turbo waste gate is sticking, you have to get underneath the front end, move the threaded rod back and forth (about 1/2 inch,it will click) with a pry bar/long screwdriver and spray it with wd40. reset eml and you should be fine to go. The reason it sticks is because it doesnt engage unless in 3rd gear at over 3000 revs

Answer (score -4):

For all you people who have problems with your car going into limp mode or sluggish at revs. Reason is that the car has been use to city speed and not been given a hammering.  Basically drive your car until it drops revs the switch the ignition off and on over and over to get the turbo to warm as the vanes are blocked. Then park up at your home and open hood and take the air intake off from the turbo to air manifold and the spray mr muscle foam oven cleaner a bit at a time.wont damage engine but you will hear a glunking noise but be brave and carry on . After you finish spray.ps leave engine on idle while you're doing this. Put the air intake pipe back on and start revving.  Drive and switch off and until  the car starts to fully  rev  up.  Do this procedure again in a month. Hope this works for you as this is how I get it done. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :) Do you have any reference for this? Just putting corrosive oven cleaner into the inlet manifold sounds so, so bad and wrong instinctively... Happy to be proven wrong though haha

Comment: The vanes block with carbon because the turbo is not used enough.  I was told to use egr cleaner but did not work . I had a lot of trouble with my wife fiat panda,  going limp mode and losing power on acceleration.  So now the car is fantastic and did not cause problems for engine.

Comment: No reference,  just been repairing cars for the last 50 years and today it's all ecu. But traditional remedies work as well.